# Datatable copy is not working properly due to some character

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatable on one of my project. Issue is that Copy is not working due to some special characters. When I am click to copy button and pasting it to excel it is not showing in correct format. Pls check the example link - [https://jsfiddle.net/bhaskarjuly26/ssLbeuqL/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/bhaskarjuly26/ssLbeuqL/6/)

In the example, first row has two fields name and position which value has javascript code.

I have also tried below code but not working:

```
  var buttonCommon = {
        exportOptions: {
            format: {
                body: function ( data, column, row ) {
                   var filterData = data.replace( /&lt;/, '<' )
                   return  filterData.replace( /&gt;/, '>' );

                }
            }
        }
    };
```

To Clear the Issue I am giving the screenshot
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Si73.png)
   Output should be same in Excel as visible in the screenshot of Step 1

Comment: That's what's in the HTML `<td>&lt;script&gt;alert("test")&lt;/script&gt;</td>`??

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here?

Comment: I want same output as showing in HTML in the excel "<script>alert("test")</script> "

Comment: it seems that the </script> is your problem.

Comment: Which is what it's doing isn't it? What you actually want is not clear

Comment: what he means is when he tries to copy the table contents.. the output for <script>alert("test")</script> is not correct rather it shows like this <script>alert("test")&lt;/script&gt;

Comment: Actually my problem is that when we click on copy button and paste it to Excel then content are not displaying correctly in the excel.

Answer (score 0):

It think this is what you need.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var buttonCommon = {
    exportOptions: {
        format: {
            body: function ( data, column, row ) {
               var filterData = data.replace( /&lt;/g, '<' )
               return  filterData.replace( /&gt;/g, '>' );

            }
        }
    }
};

$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
     buttons: [
        $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
            extend: 'copyHtml5'
        } ),
        $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
            extend: 'excelHtml5'
        } ),
        $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5'
        } )
    ]
   } );
   } );
```

Check jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ssLbeuqL/8/

[image]

Comment: When I am copy it excel it is not showing on proper format